# Mysql workbench synchronize different databases

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, mysql-workbench, mysql-gui-tools

I'm using Mysql workbench to develop my database for my application.

I use at least two databases,for example:

- **my_local** : my local testing database that it's always synchronized with mysql workbench
- **myserver_database** : the final database in the server,keep in mind that this database is in production and users WILL update it and **i can't loose any information stored into it**.

Now i can synchronyze my database every time i want but i can't find a way to update the scheme to the final server because they have different names,i get something like:

```
my_local => N/A
N/A      <= myserver_database
```

in the past i simply renamed the database in mysql workbench but it doesen't seem to work anymore,probably because of a bug.

I want to be able to synchronize the same workbench scheme with different databases,regardless of the database name,i didn't find a way to force the database name even by modifying the default_scheme.

Please keep in mind i'll do it a lot of times so it's better to avoid triky or dangerous solutions if possible.

Comment: It is not an anser on your question. You can try to compare and synchronize your databases with the help of Schema and Data Comparison tools in dbForge Studio for MySQL - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/

Comment: @Devart i'm happy with all the features in mysql workbench and it's 100% free;
i only need to fix this simple and stupid bug;i don't understand why it uses alway explicit names of databases instead of using the selected one.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old but I was able to do this on workbench 5.2.40 and there are not many updated resources online explaining how.

First I got a script of my old database:

```
mysqldump -no-data myolddb > script.sql
```

(I only want to synch the schemas, this can be done on the workbench too)

now the trick is to modify the script by adding `use mynewdb;` as its first line, this way the workbench won't say N/A or default schema nonsense.

On the workbench I created a EER model of mynewdb which is on my server, and then "Database->Synchronize with any source" and select from "model Schemadata" to "Script file" in the wizard using the script I modified initially. And then the Synch wizard worked like it should.

Comment: Thank you! The trick is to synchronize with the script instead of with an active database.